# Apache Drill query on multiple directories

Tags: apache-drill, cross-join

I use apache drill queries. I can retrieve data for separate queries, like;

```
select * from sample.file1
select * from sample.file2
```

What I need is to get results for multiple files in a folder. Is there a way to get data recursively or use cross join in apache drill?

Answer (score 0):

Query your directory:

```
select * from <dir>
```

---

Say `sample.file1` and `sample.file2` are in `/home/dev/data`

Currently you are doing something like:

```
use dfs.`/user/dev/data`
select * from sample.file1
select * from sample.file2
```

Instead use:

```
use dfs.`/user/dev`
select * from data
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution which also lets retrieve data from different folders in different hierarchy levels.

Let say, the hierarchy is;

```
| - mainFolder
| - | - folder1
| - | - | - sample1.json
| - | - | - sample2.json
| - | - | - folder2
| - | - | - | - sample4.json
| - | - folder3
| - | - | - sample5.json
| - | - | - sample6.json
```

To get all data from all the files;

```
SELECT * FROM mainFolder.* WHERE dir0=‘folder1' or dir0=‘folder3' or dir1=‘folder2';
```

where the number after "dir" represents the level of hierarchy. There is no need to give path of a folder. It checks all the folder(s) in given level(s) separately. For getting data from just folder2 `dir1='folder2'` will be enough.